# override onBackPressed from interface

Tags: java, android, interface, onbackpressed

I use many times in my app the `onBackPressed` method.

I had like to override it so it will check every time if the activity is the root activity in order to show a dialog saying "are you sure you want to exit?"

Since I use it many times in my app, I thought to create an interface and place it there.

Im new with working with interfaces but I trying the following:

```
public interface App_Interfaces {

    void BackPressed(Context contect);

}

class customBackPressed implements App_Interfaces{
    @Override
    public void BackPressed(Context context) {

        if(isTaskRoot()){

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog( context );
            dialog.setContentView( R.layout.are_you_sure );
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable( new ColorDrawable( Color.TRANSPARENT ) );
            
            if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
                dialog.show();
            }
            
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is that I get errors on `isTaskRoot` and `onBackPressed` saying the following:

```
Cannot resolve method 'isTaskRoot' in 'customBackPressed'

Cannot resolve method 'onBackPressed' in 'Object'
```

Can someone please explain to me how to work to solve this problems?

Thank you

Comment: How are you planning to use that `customBackPressed`? that class is not an `Activity` so of course it doesn't have the methods `isTaskRoot` and `onBackPressed`

Comment: Do you understand what is **isTaskRoot**? It't error because can't get taskroot, i guess mayby isTaskRoot is null in this case

Comment: You can create BaseActivity and put your login in that, all of your activities should extend base activity. I didn't get it the advantage of interface and custom back pressed class that you created

Comment: interface is used to abstract code so it wont show many times in the code no? thats what I try to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't represent behavior by interface method, you should represent it by whole interface.

```
public interface OnBackPressedListener {
    void onBackPressedEvent()
}
```

And then, you should attach this behavior to the activity/fragment/view root.
For example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnBackPressedListener {

    // Initialize your activity's fields
    
    private boolean isTaskRoot() {
    // implement your task root method
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() { // This method is provided by activity "from the box".
        onBackPressedEvent();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressedEvent() {
        if(isTaskRoot()) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView( R.layout.are_you_sure );
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable( new ColorDrawable( Color.TRANSPARENT ) );
        
            if (!this.isFinishing()) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Note that your `onBackPressedListener` interface should NOT depend on any other methods, behaviors. Its main purpose is to provide an ability to mark the class as the class, which can react to onBackPressed event.

One of the possible usages is to inherit your fragments from `onBackPressedListener` and then call their `onBackPressedEvent` methods when parent Activity is notified that back button was pressed.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // ...
    if (currFragment instanceof onBackPressedListener) {
        currFragment.onBackPressedEvent();
    }
    // ...
}
```

**UPD:** If you want to provide ready-to-use behavior for all classes inheriting `onBackPressedListener` you can use `default` keyword to create default interface method.

```
public interface onBackPressedListener() {
    boolean isTaskRoot()

    default void onBackPressedEvent() {
        // Your implementation. 
        // It should not contain calls of methods, which are not presented by this interface. 
        if (isTaskRoot()) // ...
    }
}
```

OR you can create `BaseActivity` class, in which you will override `onBackPressedEvent` from interface

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements OnBackPressedListener { 
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    ...
    }
}
```

And then you inherit your activities from it
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity { ... }

Comment: But from my understanding, I need to write the code of Overriding onBackPressed in any class that I use in my app no? I try to override it in one place and use it in all of my classes

Comment: Ye I think the last option is what I will do, thanks mate

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure... but I think it's wrong to call a method from another class in a totally different class without importing or referencing it.

your **method:**

```
'isTaskRoot'
```

is from another **class** that you didn't give information about, and your *class:*

```
customBackPressed
```

does not contain any method with that name.

I think there's a way to give access to methods through the interface... You should try and find how.